# Footer problem when using exam class with title

Tags: header-footer, titles, exam

I'm using the exam class and I want to have currentPage/totalPages printed in the footer to hopefully avoid students missing a page.

The problem is that when using /maketitle the first page always only has a '1' printed despite being configured otherwise. From the second page onward it works properly and when I don't use /maketitle it works as well.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{exam}  
\usepackage{lastpage}   
\firstpagefooter{}{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}{}
\runningfooter{}{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}{}
\title{some test}
\date{2018-01-01}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \begin{questions} 
    \question[2] A question
    \newpage
    \question[3] A question on another page
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

How can I print 1/x pages on the first page as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add  `\thispagestyle{headandfoot}` after `\maketitle` command as explained in the *exam* package documentation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{exam}  
\usepackage{lastpage} 

\footer{}{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}{}

\title{some test}
\date{2018-01-01}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \thispagestyle{headandfoot}

  \begin{questions} 
    \question[2] A question
    \newpage
    \question[3] A question on another page
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Also you can use `\footer` in place of `\firstpagefooter` and `\runningfooter`